# Flutter snackbar alternative or easier method than wrapping everything in Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, notifications, snackbar

I'm working on my first Flutter app (debugging on my Android phone). I have a list with row items. When you long-press the row, it copies the content into the user's clipboard. This is working great!

But I need to let the user know that the content was copied.

I've attempted to follow many tutorials on trying to get the row surrounded by a build method or inside a Scaffold, but I can't get any to work. Is there an alternative method to notifying the user (simply) that something like "Copied!" took place?

Notice the commented out `Scaffold.of(...` below. It just seems like there must be an easier method to notifying the user other than wrapping everything in a Scaffold. (and when I try, it breaks my layout).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/Theme.dart' as MyTheme;
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class RowRule extends StatelessWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot ruleGroup;

  RowRule(this.ruleGroup);

  _buildChildren() {
    var builder = <Widget>[];
    if (!ruleGroup['label'].isEmpty) {
      builder.add(new Text(ruleGroup['label'],
          style: MyTheme.TextStyles.articleContentLabelTextStyle));
    }
    if (!ruleGroup['details'].isEmpty) {
      builder.add(new Text(ruleGroup['details'],
          style: MyTheme.TextStyles.articleContentTextStyle));
    }
    return builder;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: ruleGroup['label'] + " "  + ruleGroup['details']));
//          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar
//            (content: Text('text copied')));
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3.0),
          child: new FlatButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
            child: new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: MyTheme.Dimens.ruleGroupListRowMarginVertical),
                  child: new Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: _buildChildren(),
                        ),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
  }
```

The goal is to have a page like this (see image), which I have, and it works and scrolls...etc, but I cannot get it to work with a Scaffold, and therefore, haven't been able to use the snackbar. Each "Row" (which this file is for) should show a snackbar on longPress.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These is a simple plugin replacement for the Snackbar named "Flushbar". 
You can get the plugin here - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar 
You don't have to take care of any wrapping of widgets into scaffold also you get a lot of modifications for you like background gradient, adding forms and so on into Snackbar's and all. 
Inside your onLongPressed in GestureDetectore you can do this.

```
onLongPressed:(){
Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: ruleGroup['label'] + " "  + ruleGroup['details']));
Flushbar(
             message:  "Copied !!",
             duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),              
          )..show(context);
}
```

This will display the snackbar in you app where you would want to see it also you can get a lot of modification available to you so the you can make it look as per your app.

Comment: What's the clipboard for? Is that even related to your answer?

Comment: FYI: Flushbar is DISCONTINUED. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar

Answer (score 8):

You can use `GlobalKey` to make it work the way you want it.

[image]

Since I don't have access to your database stuff, this is how I gave you an idea to do it. Copy and paste this code in your class and make changes accordingly. I also believe there is something wrong in your `RowRule` class, can you just copy the full code I have given you and run?

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.9),
      key: _key,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(52, 56, 245, 1),
            height: 150,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(width: 56, padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12), decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.yellow)),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              itemCount: 120,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("Row #$index"),
                    onLongPress: () => _key.currentState
                      ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Copied \"Row #$index\""))),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a Scaffold in this file/layout. I've seen this as a suggested method, but how do I get the GlobalKey to be accessable here? All the examples I've seen are like this, where the Scaffold is in the same file as the longPress.

Comment: @Dave You can wrap your widget in `Scaffold` easily, make `GestureDetector` child of `Scaffold` in your example.

Comment: When I wrap the GestureDetector with Scaffold, and make the GestureDetecttor it's "body", I get: `Another exception was thrown: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.` The same error also for "_RenderInkFeatures", "RenderPhysicalModel", "RenderRepaintBoundary", and "RenderIndexedSemantics".

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you need to do, like use `onPressed` property of the `FlatButton` it is mandatory to allow clicks, wrap your `GestureDetector` in a `Scaffold`. I have further modified the code so that it uses `GlobalKey` to make things easy for you.

Here is the final code (**Your way**)

```
class RowRule extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey = GlobalKey();
  final DocumentSnapshot ruleGroup;

  RowRule(this.ruleGroup);

  _buildChildren() {
    var builder = <Widget>[];
    if (!ruleGroup['label'].isEmpty) {
      builder.add(new Text(ruleGroup['label'], style: MyTheme.TextStyles.articleContentLabelTextStyle));
    }
    if (!ruleGroup['details'].isEmpty) {
      builder.add(new Text(ruleGroup['details'], style: MyTheme.TextStyles.articleContentTextStyle));
    }
    return builder;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: ruleGroup['label'] + " " + ruleGroup['details']));
          globalKey.currentState
            ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
            ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('text copied')));
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3.0),
          child: new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => print("Handle button press here"),
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
            child: new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: MyTheme.Dimens.ruleGroupListRowMarginVertical),
                  child: new Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: _buildChildren(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This throws the following error: `RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.`

Answer (score 1):

I made a dropdown banner [package](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_banner) on pub that allows you to easily notify users of errors or confirmation of success. It's a work in progress as I continue to add visually rich features.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your `build()` method is completed or you are yet to change it, because it consist of many widgets which are just redundant. Like there is no need to have `Container` in `Container` and further `Padding` along with a `FlatButton` which would make complete screen clickable. Also having `Column` won't be a good idea because your screen may overflow if you have more data. Use `ListView` instead.

So, if you were to take my advice, use this simple code that should provide you what you are really looking for. (See the `build()` method is of just 5 lines.

```
class RowRule extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey = GlobalKey();

  final DocumentSnapshot ruleGroup;

  RowRule(this.ruleGroup);

  _buildChildren() {
    var builder = <Widget>[];
    if (!ruleGroup['label'].isEmpty) {
      builder.add(
        ListTile(
          title: Text(ruleGroup['label'], style: MyTheme.TextStyles.articleContentLabelTextStyle),
          onLongPress: () {
            globalKey.currentState
              ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
              ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Clicked")));
          },
        ),
      );
    }
    if (!ruleGroup['details'].isEmpty) {
      builder.add(
        ListTile(
          title: Text(ruleGroup['details'], style: MyTheme.TextStyles.articleContentTextStyle),
          onLongPress: () {
            globalKey.currentState
              ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
              ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Clicked")));
          },
        ),
      );
    }
    return builder;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      body: ListView(children: _buildChildren()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I get many errors, some of which are the same as I experience whenever I try to use a Scaffold: "Another exception was thrown: _RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout." and a number of others.

Comment: Can you please share the class where you are using `RowRule`?

Answer (score 0):

I read your comments on all answers and here is my conslusion:

You need `ScaffoldState` object that is just above the widget in tree to show `Snackbar`. You can either get it through `GlobalKey` as many have suggested. Fairly simple if the `Scaffold` is created inside `build` of the widget, but if it is outside the widget (in your case) then it becomes complicated. You need to pass that key, wherever you need it through Constructor arguments of child widgets.

`Scaffold.of(context)` is a very neat way to just do that. Just like an [InheritedWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html), [`Scaffold.of(BuildContext context)`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html) gives you access of the closest `ScaffoldState` object above the tree. Else it could be a nightmare to get that instance (by passing it through as constructor arguments) if your tree was very deep.

Sorry, to disappoint but I don't think there is any better or cleaner method than this, if you want to get the `ScaffoldState` that is not built inside build of that widget. You can call it in any widget that has `Scaffold` as a parent.

Comment: `Scaffold.of(context)` has nothing to do wirth InheritedWidgets

Comment: @RémiRousselet I did some searching, and you are right Scafoold is not an IW, but it does provide a similar `.of()`  static method to get the closest State object. I just assumed it would be IW. Anyways corrected my answer. Thanks for enlighenting me!!